# How do I stop data from continuing to second record in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports, report

my title could be a bit confusing...I will explain in details here.

My current problem is that I am creating a report for a company, when I select only 1 vendor at a time, the report works fine. Please look at the picture 1 below for further details:

[image: Picture 1]

So basically, the report will only show the amount when the value is not 0. Note that at "Bal. Amount", the data is calculate by the formula:

> ```
> CurrencyVar Amount;
> Amount := Amount + ({@DebitAmt} - {@CreditAmt});
> ```

However, when I chose a range of different vendors. The report went haywire. Now let's take a look at second picture:

[image: Picture 2]

If you notice it, the last result in Picture 1 was 605.00. The report took the data and deduct the 2160.00.

What I really want is to start fresh and make sure the report doesn't take the data from previous vendor...how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by vendor and do your calculations according to the group... so that there will be fresh entry for the each time vendor changes

Edit..............................................................

Place fields in details and take summary in group footer and write your calculation part `Bal Amount` in group footer itself and supress the details

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Use a running-total field; key is to reset the field's value on change of vendor
2. Use your current approach (manual, running total), but add the missing logic:

```
// {@reset}
// place in group-header section

WhilePrintingRecords;
CurrencyVar Amount:=0;


// {@increment}
// place in details section

WhilePrintingRecords;
CurrencyVar Amount + ({@DebitAmt} - {@CreditAmt});

// {@display}
// place in group-footer section

WhilePrintingRecords;
CurrencyVar Amount;
```